# Can I with a MemberInfo check if the member is a delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, member

Is it possible with a `MemberInfo` to check if member is a delegate? How I can know if the `MemberInfo` is a type that extends `MulticastDelegate`?

Answer (score 1):

`MemberInfo` does not expose this information. You would have to figure out which of the super types it is, like `FieldInfo` and check a property like `FieldType` or `PropertyType` on `PropertyInfo`.